# Deploy JSP webproject to tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, webserver, tomcat7, intranet

How can I make my web application run on tomcat server? I want to run my web application in intranet. Is there a proper tool or software to do this?

Comment: do you mean it should be accessible via other people in the same network ? if so explore -b option

Comment: @JayaramPradhan yes. access it with specific IP? cloud you give me some tutorial or link of some videos of how can I do this? I really have no idea of how to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036859/how-to-access-tomcat-form-another-computer