# How can I let other devices (not in my LAN) onto my Tomcat 7 server?

Tags: tomcat, server, tomcat7

First of all, this is my first server so I don't know how to do pretty much anything, so please use simple words if possible. I want to be able to have certain devices (or whole routers, if possible) to be able to get on my server. I've looked around a lot and I can't find anything on how to do this. What I have found either confuses me a lot, isn't what I need, doesn't explain what to do, or is a combination of those. I am able to configure port forwarding as needed. My Tomcat 7 server is currently working through LAN perfect (on port 8080, in case that's important). I will gladly give any information needed and **try** to check often. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. For this general type of question, it would be good to include some references to documentation that you have found even if that documentation isn't completely clear. Please see these guidelines [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Some of the most notable ones I used are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036859/how-to-access-tomcat-from-another-computer  -  Found out I need to set up port forwarding. https://superuser.com/questions/899865/how-can-i-access-my-server-from-outside-of-my-lan  -  I dont know what this means. https://lifehacker.com/5831841/know-your-network-lesson-4-accessing-your-home-computers-from-anywhere  -  This was possibly the most helpful, but it's not what I want. To be clear, I just want to be able to get onto my server from outside my LAN, not access my computer, which is what I've found.