# After deploying java web application, How to use this on another machine

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jsp

I have created a java web application and deployed on Apache tomcat (v8)on my own machine. So my question is, how can another person use my deployed application to their machine.
What I need to do for that?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134309/how-can-i-browse-my-tomcat-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-network ... Please check the Stack Overflow knowledge base before posting a question.

Comment: Sorry for same question but, want to know that How can i run my java web application on different network..

Answer (score 0):

The exact steps you need to take will depend on the type of network where your Tomcat is running.  Here is a brief guideline of steps to configure Tomcat for remote network access:

1) Figure out the port number on which Tomcat is listening.  The default is 8080, though that may lead to conflicts.  If you wish/need to change the port number you can update the `<Connector>` tag from the `server.xml` file.

2) Remove any firewalls on your network and Tomcat port.

3) Open that port to the outside, so that your external requests will be routed to your Tomcat.  The network where Tomcat is running has an **external** IP address which is visible to the outside.  You need to instruct your network to forward all incoming requests to that IP address on port 8080 (or whatever port number you have chosen for Tomcat) to the computer running Tomcat.

If you do all these steps correctly, then your Tomcat webapp should be accessible from outside that network.  Note that you have effectively launched your webapp to the whole world, so make sure this is what you really want to do.

Here is a good site which discusses the concepts and steps for opening a port on a router: http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/